# PHP use Parent variable in Extended Class

Tags: php, class, variables

I can't get a grip on this concept. I want to use a simple variable from my parent class in the extended class. This variable is flexible and might be calculated somewhere in a Method inside the parent class.

```
class Class1 {
    public $owner;

    function set_owner () {
        $this->owner = "Me";
        return $this->owner;
    }
}

class Class2 extends Class1 {

    function show_owner () {
        return $this->owner;
    }
}

$Class1 = new Class1();
$Class2 = new Class2();

echo "<p>owner set: ".$Class1->set_owner()."</p>";
echo "<p>owner get: ".$Class2->show_owner()."</p>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `static` like so:

```
class Class1 {
    public static $owner;

    function set_owner () {
        self::$owner = "Me";
        return self::$owner;
    }
}

class Class2 extends Class1 {

    function show_owner () {
        return self::$owner;
    }
}

$Class1 = new Class1();
$Class2 = new Class2();

echo "<p>owner set: ".$Class1->set_owner()."</p>";
echo "<p>owner get: ".$Class2->show_owner()."</p>";
```

Output:

```
owner set: Me

owner get: Me
```

Comment: would doing `return $this->owner;` work in the class 2? @ShlomoGoldstein

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 different objects.

You can use the same object like this:

```
$Class2 = new Class2();

echo "<p>owner set: ".$Class2->set_owner()."</p>";
echo "<p>owner get: ".$Class2->show_owner()."</p>";
```

Or if you want to have 2 objects you can also use static properties (but it is bad practice and hard to test).

Answer (score 1):

`$Class1`  is a different object & `$Class2` is different object , hence `$owner` variable is different  for both of them

What you are doing is

```
        echo "<p>owner set: ".$Class1->set_owner()."</p>";  //set the owner variable of Class1
        echo "<p>owner get: ".$Class2->show_owner()."</p>"; // get the owner variable of Class2  , $owner is different for Class2
```

This will print what you want

```
        echo "<p>owner set: ".$Class2->set_owner()."</p>";  //set the owner variable of Class2
        echo "<p>owner get: ".$Class2->show_owner()."</p>"; // get the owner variable of Class2
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember Class != object. Class2 inherits form Class1 but the class1 object sets a value to the variable and the class2 object does not inherit from the class1 object. But you can set the $owner property to static to achive this.

Demo: https://eval.in/106931

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. I will try my best though!

When you extend your parent class `(Class1)` the `public` and `protected` `properties` and `methods` can be used or over-ridden by the `child` class.

The owner variable is visible and can be used by child class. But it is in a different `namespace` because of this statement: `$Class2 = new Class2()`;

calling `echo var_dump($Class2->show_owner());` shows `NULL` data-type.